# How to receive input as yyyyMMddHHmm format in java?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
java.util.Date parsedDate = sdf.parse("201212130900");
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
try
{
  PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "select count(*) as counter from table1 where table_key > ?");
  pstmt.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(timestamp.getTime()));  
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  
  while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getInt( 1 ));
  }
  connection.close();
}
catch(Exception g){
  System.err.println(g.getMessage());
}
```

In the output I am receiving an error as

> ORA-01843: not a valid month.

Can anyone assist to solve the above error ?

Comment: Your column "table_key" is a TIMESTAMP?

Comment: yes...the table_key will have value something like this "201212120147693401252790" with which I dedeuced that format to be like this "yyyyMMddHHmm" and to query in DB it is enough if we give table_key > 'yyyyMMddHHmm' the results will be retrieved.

Comment: @PrashanthK The month then would be 13 (char's 5 & 6).  Perhaps you have day and month switched?

Comment: yes...I realized it and I changed the example value now..

Comment: It might help if you posted your table definition. Also, can you get a query to work using an interactive SQL tool?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
       java.util.Date parsedDate = sdf.parse("201212130900");
       java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
       System.out.println(new java.sql.Timestamp(timestamp.getTime()));` seems to be working fine. I suspect, its values in your database causing the problem.

Comment: Aaron..I see the table_key is of type CHAR

Comment: Yogendra singh...with desc table1 and for table_key I see it to be as CHAR(24)...so am I trying to do with a date field but actually its declared a CHAR in DB ? anymore conversion I have to do ?

Answer (score 1):

In java, to get a formated date, you would do the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
String sdf.format(myDate);
```

There are loads of options in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  I have attached the JavaDoc for you.

Comment: Isn't the OP using the same?

Comment: not sure what this means "Isn't the OP using the same" ? can you please elaborate it a bit more

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion from string to timestap is OK.(I tested and works).

---

You problem may be in the time zone or something.
Try to use this method instead,

```
setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x, Calendar cal)
```

Example:

```
setTimestamp(1, timestamp , Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")))
```

---

**UPDATED:** (table1.table_key is an CHAR(24))

You should give you date from java in a String, assuming key_value is formatted as "yyyyMMddhhmm"... (for obvious reasons other format will not work)

Other option is in your query convert key_value to TIMESTAMP

Try: (I'm assuming you are working with oracle db, and I do some search)

1) Do a "cast" to  timestamp

"select count(*) as counter from table1 where timestamp(table_key) > ?"

2)Using http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm .
I do not know if you can do something like this:

"select count(*) as counter from table1 where TO_TIMESTAMP(table_key,'YYYYMMDDHHMMHH24MI') > ?"

Comment: I tried like this pstmt.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(timestamp.getTime()),Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))); and I got the error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
Did I try correctly ?

Comment: Ok. Some questions:
You are using oracle data base?
Please update your post with your table definition.
which timezone and locale your db is defined ? 

Other thing, you could just give as parameter the timestamp you created above.

Comment: okay...I am very happy to receive exciting inputs. and the table_key is of type CHAR(24) apart from this it would be difficult for me divulge any other details.I would suggest a work around...can we approach a solution to my problem by considering the DB to be located in any country of ur wish and try to solve it ?

Comment: nms...can you please share more on how to convert a string to timestamp..in line with the code I have posted above ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above problem.

I converted the date to "yyyyMMdd" format and converted the time in "HHmm" format, storing them as 2 different strings.