# java Mismatch between date String and the converted date

Tags: java, date

Try to have a function that can validate a input date string.
For example `201807192113` indicates 2018/07/09 21:13

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat CASSANDRA_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMddHHmm");

private static boolean isValidateDate(final String input) {

    try {
        CASSANDRA_DATE_FORMAT.setLenient(false);
        final Date date = CASSANDRA_DATE_FORMAT.parse(input);
        System.out.println(date.toString());

        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final boolean validateDate = FCXTablesValidation.isValidateDate("201807200101");
    System.out.println(validateDate);
}
```

While the output is `Sun Dec 31 21:13:00 EST 2017
true`, which indicates another date.

Also, if passed in `201807322113` which is not a valid date(32 is not a valid day in a month), still got the same output.

Comment: You are using `"YYYY"` as the format of year. `Y` is the pattern letter for [week of year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year).  To be honest I don't know how the mentioned output is parsed from the input string. But if you use the pattern letter `y`the lenient setting will throw a `ParseException`. So is it intended to use the pattern letter `Y`?

Comment: Are you saying that if you pass `"201807200101"` to this method, it prints `Sun Dec 31 21:13:00 EST 2017`?  Are you sure?

Comment: @LuCio - Actually `Y` is "week year", not "week of year".  Lower case `w` is "week of year".

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes, you're right. I should have copy&paste it ;) "week year" is also where I have linked to using the link in the JavaDoc of `SimpleDateFormat`. But nonetheless, your objection is  justified.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Duplicates of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46581387/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28858787/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49763466/642706), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13868251/642706). [One of my own Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939890/642706) has the exact code snippet you need.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).